# Redirecting stderr and stdout back to terminal?

Tags: ruby

Currently, I have:

```
$stdout.sync = true
$stderr.sync = true
orig_stdout = $stdout.clone
orig_stderr = $stderr.clone
$stdout.reopen("log.txt","w")
$stderr.reopen("log.txt","w")

#Run some processes that I want to hide from user view

$stdout.reopen(orig_stdout)
$stderr.reopen(orig_stderr)

#Display feedback on processes completing and continue with Ruby program. 
end
```

However, when I run this, Ruby does not send stdout and stderr back to the terminal. They are held from being displayed until program process is killed, and then they are displayed on the terminal.

Is there a way to swap the stdout and stderr back to the terminal instantly?
Thank you

## EDIT:

At
    #Run some processes that I want to hide from user view
I also require in those processes user-input for a svn username as well as a svn password. 
This is why the program would not output back to the terminal.

I still would need to be able to redirect all the output to a "log.txt" file and back again, but with implementation of svn.

Comment: There's a similar question here with an accepted answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9254681/reassigning-global-stdout-to-console-ruby

Comment: Check what I had edited. I had used that answer and several others to get to what I have now. Problem is, I need it to work around SVN parameters, which was causing the output not to be switched.

Comment: What version of Ruby are you running?  I tested your code as-written in `irb` (ruby 1.8.7) and it worked for me.

Comment: I don't understand what you meran by "with implementation of svn", can you clarify?

Comment: @user1612173 A few things. (1) Please post/tag your version of Ruby in the question. (2) When you say SVN do you mean that you want to check the log statements (in `log.txt`) into version control? That is usually not a good idea, as you can quickly rack up space in the repository. (3) It looks like after your edit you are asking 2 questions now. Please refine your question body to have all the details, without tacking on an EDIT. (4) What are your error messages? What is your expected result? Has it worked before?

Comment: Can you please clarify what this means?  "Ruby does not send stdout and stderr back to the terminal. They are held from being displayed until program process is killed, and then they are displayed on the terminal."  Which stdout and stderr output is being held?  Is it the output from the process?  Is it what your program is writing when it "displays feedback on processes"?

Answer (score 0):

It's a old question, I found myself in the same situation. I wrote a Multi-IO Class which extends `File` and overrode `write` `puts` and `close` methods, I also made sure its thread safe:

```
require 'singleton'

class MultiIO < File
  include Singleton 
  @@targets = []
  @@mutex = Mutex.new

  def self.instance
    self.open('/dev/null','w+')
  end

  def puts(str)
    write "#{str}\n"
  end

  def write(str)
    @@mutex.synchronize do 
      @@targets.each { |t| t.write str; flush }
    end
  end

  def setTargets(targets)
    raise 'setTargets is a one-off operation' unless @@targets.length < 1
    targets.each do |t|
       @@targets.push STDOUT.clone if t == STDOUT 
       @@targets.push STDERR.clone if t == STDERR
       break if t == STDOUT or t == STDERR  
       @@targets.push(File.open(t,'w+'))
    end
    self
  end

  def close
    @@targets.each {|t| f.close}
  end
end

STDOUT.reopen MultiIO.instance.setTargets(['/tmp/1.log',STDOUT,STDERR])
STDERR.reopen STDOUT 


threads = []

5.times.each do |i| 
  threads.push( 
    Thread.new do
      10000.times.each do |j|
        STDOUT.puts "out#{i}:#{j}"
      end
    end
  )
end

5.times.each do |i| 
  threads.push( 
    Thread.new do
      10000.times.each do |j|
        STDERR.puts "err#{i}:#{j}"
      end
    end
  )
end

threads.each {|t| t.join}
```